# WebComponents Support in IE 11 - PolyFills

Tags: javascript, google-web-component

I've got a web component working in chrome.  I am trying to get it to show up in IE 11.

I've added this line in my main index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/headerComponent/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

I have copied file to said directory.  After I rebuild and deploy my site, I am not seeing the web component in IE, in Chrome it shows OK.

Am I missing something?

**Update 9/6/2017**

I am now getting this error:

File: webcomponents-lite.js, Line: 137, Column: 460
Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference

Line is this:

```
var a=this.ownerDocument;if(a&&a.contains&&a.contains(this)||(a=a.documentElement)&&
```

So, it looks like the polyfill is loading but not executing properly.  Also, I put in some console.log in the connected and disconnected call backs and they are not being called as well.

Comment: Any errors popping up in the console?

Comment: F12ing, I don't see any errors in the console.  If I look at the DOM, it looks incomplete as opposed to the DOM that renders in Chrome.

Comment: Can you try using the full webcomponent JS library?

Comment: yes, let me try that, thx

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: No, still woking on it.  I am adding some logging on the disconnected callbacks to see if they are being called.  If I do a customElements.define it returns the function so the polyfill is being loaded but the custom component is not being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these polyfill(s)/libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/headerComponent/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/headerComponent/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
```

Also, placement makes a difference.  I put these right after the head tag.  After the body was not working as DOM manipulation needs to happen.

I added the custom-elements.min.js since we were using the v1 spec of the custom elements as well.

After this, the web components were visible in IE 11.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for updating this thread! Upvoted!

Comment: Can you add an http link instead of referencing it from your local directory

Comment: Could you provide a source for the polyfills?

Comment: Here you go
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/webcomponentsjs/0.5.2